# Is it possible to access the prototype variable GLOBALLY

Tags: javascript

```
function Person() {}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function(){
    var name = "John Micheal";
}

var p1 = new Person();
console.log(p1.getFullName());
```

Here I want to access the variable "name" to my other prototypes. Is this possible?

If not, Is there any other way to do ?

http://jsfiddle.net/KabeerRifaye/bcxqx1wj/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean accessing the `getFullName`?

Comment: *"Here I want to access the variable "name" to my other prototypes"* What does that mean?

Comment: yes. I would like to use the name"John Micheal" to another prototype. If I make the var "name" get out from "Person.prototype.getFullName".  so that I can easily access it for my other prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go do some JavaScript tutorials. I recommend TreeHouse or CodeSchool.

Anyways, there are a few possible options / interpretations of your question.

If you're just trying to get the return value you need to use the `return` keyword. Now your `console.log` will output the name.

```js
function Person() {}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function(){
  var name = "John Micheal";
  return name;
}

var p1 = new Person();
console.log(p1.getFullName());
```

If you truly want to share the value between functions you need to use the `this` keyword. In this example you can set the value in `setName` and retrieve it with `getName`.

```js
function Person() {}

Person.prototype.getName = function(){
  return this.name
}

Person.prototype.setName = function(newName) {
  this.name = newName
}

var p1 = new Person();

p1.setName('John');
console.log(p1.getName());
```

These are hard concepts to learn on your own. I really recommend working through some JavaScript tutorials to learn this fundamental concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your version => http://jsfiddle.net/bcxqx1wj/3/

I would highly recommend to use a more generic get function:

```
Person.prototype.getData = function(prop){
    if (this[prop] !== undefined) {
        return this[prop];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Set function would look like this:

```
Person.prototype.setData = function(prop, data){
    this[prop] = data;
}
```